# Correct way to use function pointers for traversal bst

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, function-pointers, traversal, inorder

i am creating a binary search tree template class, and want to use function pointers for the inorder traversal function, i am okay with function pointers but for some reason am lost on how to use the inorder once the code is in place. not much other stuff online has helped me so any feed back would be great.

```
class Bst
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;
        Node(T key) :data(key), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
    };

    typedef void(*inorderPtr)(T &);
    typedef void(*preorderPtr)(T &);
    typedef void(*postorderPtr)(T &);

    Node * root;
    T & GetItem() const;
    void deleteNode(Node*);
    void printNode(Node*);
    void inorder(Node * root, void (*inorderPtr)(T &)) const;
    void preorder(Node * root) const;
    void postorder(Node * root) const;

public:

    Bst();
    ~Bst();
    Bst(const Bst<T> & source);
    const Bst<T> & operator = (const Node &);
    void insert(const T);
    void print();
    void inorder(void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const;
    void printPreorder() const;
    void printPostorder() const;
};
```

some code is as follows for basic bst

```
template<class T>
inline T & Bst<T>::GetItem() const
{
    return data;
}

template<class T>
inline void Bst<T>::inorder(Node * root, void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const
{
    if (root->left != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(root->left, inorderPtr);
    }

    inorderPtr(root->GetItem());

    if (root->right != nullptr)
    {
        inorder(root->right, inorderPtr);
    }
}

template<class T>
inline void Bst<T>::inorder(void(*inorderPtr)(T &)) const
{   
    inorder(this->root, inorderPtr);
}
```

```
int main()
{
        Bst<int> tree;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        tree.insert(i);
    }

    tree.inorder();

}
```

the main is basic test but having trouble with inorder(); not enough arguments

Comment: Don't use function pointers. Use `std::function` and closures (lambda expressions)

Comment: Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: whether i use them or not i still would like to knoiw

Comment: Bad [MCVE], you need not only to give the code, but also the diagnostics when compiling it, or explain the bad behavior when running it. So bad question, that I voted to close.

Comment: I think you meant `typedef void(Bst::*inorderPtr)(T &);` and then `(this->*inorderPtr)(root->...);`. This code, as it's now, makes no sense to me. What does the `inorder` function do?

Comment: You call the `inorder` function, which requires an argument. But you don't pass an argument.

Comment: yeah i dont know what function to pass it thats why im confused with the bst template traversal

Comment: It seems to me that your main problem is that you don't know what you're really supposed to do. You seem to have the actual inorder traversal working, all you need is to pass a pointer to a function that does something with the node data. But if you don't know what you're supposed to do then it becomes very hard. You need to pass a pointer to a function, but what should the function ***do?*** When you know that, just create such a function (as a global non-member function) and pass a pointer to it.

Comment: What do you want to call? The `typedef void(*inorderPtr)(T &);` names a type, not a member variable. Then you introduce a variable `void(*inorderPtr)(T &)` inside `void Bst<T>::inorder` and want to call it. What function do you want to pass there? We can't answer that, it's a design choice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah man im getting confused on what i need to do, i did basic function pointers n attempted this and i cant wrap my head around it. sorry if it seems dumb im just hella lost rn.

Comment: ok so this post here https://techqa.club/v/q/c-recursive-traversals-with-function-pointers-c3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvd3wyMDczMTI= is pre much the same but i dont understand how they passed print_val in to their function

Comment: @Getwrong: But to understand that you need to read dozens of pages. StackOverflow is not the right place to expect such a long answer; you should not expect us to write an answer of many pages! You are supposed to *research knowledge* before asking here.

Comment: As explained in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56232001/841108), in your case above, **you should not use function pointers** (but closures!) Is your goal to solve a problem (inorder traversal) or just to use obsolete C++ programming style. Remember, current C++ is C++11 at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you want to print the value of each node in the tree:

```
void value_printer(int& value)
{
    std::cout << "Value is " << value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    Bst<int> tree;

    // Insert nodes...

    tree.inorder(&value_printer);
}
```

You pass a pointer to the `value_printer` function in the `inorder` call. That function will then be called for each node in the traversal.

The function you pass a pointer to can do other things, of course. And as it is currently declared, you can even modify the values of the tree.

Learn more about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56232001/841108) answer.

Comment: @Getwrong: this is *not* perfect. You should use `std::function`

Comment: i know but this explained what i wanted to know perfectly thankyou @someprogrammerdude

Comment: No, you should learn genuine C++. The above code is not. Even if it works.

Comment: yeah i know and understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You need to spend weeks in reading more about C++. Remember, **C++ is a very difficult programming language** (even with 5 years of practice, you won't be an expert in C++; I do code in C++ but I am not expert in it; the C++ experts are perhaps only a few dozens only on Earth). And don't learn anything older than [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and preferably [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) (since we are in 2019, so most recent C++ compiler are already C++17 compliant, and all of them accept C++11; if your compiler don't know about C++11, update your C++ compiler).

<sup>(if you are required to code in [C++03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B03) or some earlier C++, instead of C++11, ask for a pay raise, because then you are using obsolete tools. Today, in 2019, coding in C++03 is like coding in [COBOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL): it needs a rare skill that has monetary value.)</sup>

So first, **read a good C++ book**, such as [*Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++*](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) (by the designer of C++). Then look into some [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site. Read also [*how to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (very relevant here).

Then, **compile with all warnings and debug info**. If your compiler is [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with `g++ -Wall -g` at least. *You'll get a nice diagnostic message. Show it in your question please*.

At last, you declared your `inorder` as taking one argument, and you don't give any when calling that (and by so doing you are inconsistent):

```
   tree.inorder();
   //           ^     missing argument
```

You wrongly asked:

> I am creating a binary search tree template class, and want to use *function pointers*

As I commented, you should **avoid [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)** (they are so C like, not genuine C++), and use some [`std::function` type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) in the [declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations) of that `inorder`, and pass perhaps some anonymous [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) at its [call site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_site). Because what you *should* pass conceptually is not a function pointer, but a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) (which combines a raw function pointer with data, the closed values), or, if you unfortunately want to avoid genuine C++ and stay compatible with plain C [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) style and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention), have [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) so pass not only a raw function pointer but also some client data.

So you really want to declare and define (like most [C++ containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) do)

```
template<class T>
inline void Bst<T>::inorder(std::function<void(T&)> fun) const;
```

(later, as an *optimization*, you might pass `fun` as a `const` [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)) and you would use it (with a lambda expression) like, for example:

```
tree.inorder([](T& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; });
```

I claim that your teacher should first teach you about closures ands how to nicely use them in some [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style (which is quite natural in your case), and then explain their *implementation* by also, and later, teaching function pointers. In most cases, **function pointers are obsolete in C++** (but they exist for compatibility with C and obsolete versions of C++).

PS. What you don't understand takes several dozens of pages to explain (since the C++ [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) is very complex). We don't have that much space here (and time to write it). Please **take a week to read a good C++ book**.

Comment: yeah i know i dont give it an arguement, i put it there to show what i mean. how do i use the inorder is what im asking

Comment: You use it in a way consistent with its declaration.